# How to take my view as a picture osx

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to take my `NSView`(With layers) as an image can I do so in OSX ?

in iOS I would do the following

```
-(UIImage*) makeImage//snapshot the view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```

I tried this solution from 1 of the SO answers

```
[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[view dataWithPDFInsideRect:[view bounds]]];
```

but it didn't work because I have layers in my `NSView`.

I started from converting UI to NS 
and now I have warnings on every line :)

```
-(NSImage*) makeImage :(RMBlurredView*)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    NSImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return viewImage;
}
```

I am not familiar with OSX can some 1 help me to convert this code to OSX ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

drawing to the image is tad different than in iOS:

1. you create a blank image, LOCK on to it, so all drawing goes to that graphics context

   ```
   NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
   [image lockFocus];
   ```
2. you draw your layer same as on iOS

   ```
   CGContextRef ctx = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext].graphicsPort;
   [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
   ```
3. unlock image

   ```
   [image unlockFocus];
   ```

**NOTE this is only if your view is layered. it doesn't work for non-layered views!**
your view -as shown above- is layer backed so all's fine ;)

Comment: Thank you very much :) 
-BTW it is my route to handle the previous question , I couldn't find how to make gif through out the layered view , so i decided to draw all its static conents and then to take this snapShot and add it as regular nsview with apicture inside :)

Comment: I answered this today :) you have to set imageView.canDrawSubviewsInLayer = YES so animated gifs work. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969667/how-to-display-animated-gif-in-objective-c-on-top-of-the-layered-view/23969766#23969766

Comment: However I feel sad with this solution , but it works like a charm :)

Comment: Oh I didnt see that -> didn't recieve anything from SO about your update , I am trying it now I hope it will work :)) Thanks you :)