# Alternative method for canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer prior to OSX 10.9

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, calayer, nsimage, nsimageview

I needed to implement the following code in my image view to make a gif properly animate:

```
self.homeView.radarImageView.animates = YES;
self.homeView.radarImageView.canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer = YES;
self.homeView.radarImageView.image = currentData.radarImage;
```

Unfortunately, the `canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer` method is not compatible with OSX prior to 10.9.  Is there an alternative approach that I can use that will make this work in OSX 10.7 and higher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

avoid layer-based views under 10.8 and below as they don't seem to mix well with  animated gifs

see:
[How to display animated GIF in Objective C on top of the layered View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969667/how-to-display-animated-gif-in-objective-c-on-top-of-the-layered-view/23969766)

#### edit:

as asked in the comment, one can draw gradients (and all other effects without using layers)
For Gradients for example there is NSGradient that takes NSColors and can fill a rect

#### shameless plug:

A NSView that can draw all that you ever want in your background: color, gradient, patttern image, just an image, a border, rounded corners... all in one view
https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDBackgroundView

Comment: I have layered backed views so I can create a gradient color for the background. How would I do this if the view is not layer backed?